# ignore empty string in a list or when there is a $none

Tags: python

I would like to totally ignored these lists within a list when there is an empty string or when there is a "$none" string (by the way, why does this "$none" appears and what does it mean?). In my program, I returned the list an empty string when using this:

Code:

```
aaa = ["mom", "is", "king"]
example = ["buying", "mom", "is", "spending"]
```

Below code:

```
for x in aaa:
    if xx in example:
        if x in xx:
            return ""
        else:
            return xx
```

**I only know how to return an empty string but do not know other way of ignore this part of "if" when triggered**

If the above cannot be done, then the below will be my main question.

My code:

```
a = [['checking-$none', ''],
['', 'checking-some'],
['checking-people', 'checking-might'],
['-checking-too', 'checking-be']]


for x in a:
    f = filter(None, x)
    for ff in f:
        print(ff)
```

Current output:

```
checking-$none
checking-some
checking-people
checking-might
-checking-too
checking-be
```

Expected output:

```
checking-people
checking-might
-checking-too
checking-be
```

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension like this:

```
[item for lst in a if all(item and '$none' not in item for item in lst) for item in lst]
```

With your sample input `a`, this returns:

```
['checking-people', 'checking-might', '-checking-too', 'checking-be']
```

Alternatively, if you only want to print, the following nested `for` loop will do:

```
for lst in a:
    for item in lst:
        if not item or '$none' in item:
            break
    else:
        print(*lst, sep='\n')
```

This outputs:

```
checking-people
checking-might
-checking-too
checking-be
```

Comment: Nice answer, but maybe consider expanding on those variable names ;-) It' s a bit confusing. Playing devil's advocate, it would make the list comp longer and perhaps uglier, but I think that's not too bad of a trade-off for having descriptive variable names. Other than that, nice answer, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Min change to you code would be filter out string that contains $none

```
a = [['checking-$none', ''],
['', 'checking-some'],
['checking-people', 'checking-might'],
['-checking-too', 'checking-be']]



f = filter(lambda y: '' not in y and "checking-$none" not in y, a)
for x in sum(f, []): 
    print(x)
```